# How to Move UIView using touchesMoved having affineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I have UIView which is transform vertically by using

```
currentView.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0f)));
```

Now I need to move this UIView from one location to other by using touches, for this I have used

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

But I am not able to maintain the transform, How we can achive this?

Basically I have added some UI elements on UIView using following call

```
-(void)AddItemOnView:(UIView*)aView
               Angle:(CGFloat)aDegree
             XOrigin:(CGFloat)aXOrigin
             YOrigin:(CGFloat)aYOrigin
               Width:(CGFloat)aWidth
              Height:(CGFloat)aHeight
               FlipX:(CGFloat)aFlipHorrizontal
               FlipY:(CGFloat)aFlipVerticle
{
    UIView* currentView = aView;
    if(currentView)
    {
        CGFloat angle = aDegree;
        CGFloat flipHorrizontal = aFlipHorrizontal;
        CGFloat flipVerticle = aFlipVerticle;
        CGFloat xOrigin = aXOrigin;
        CGFloat yOrigin = aYOrigin;
        CGFloat width = aWidth;
        CGFloat height = aHeight;

        currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        currentView.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));

        /* Flip The View Horrizontly*/
        if(flipHorrizontal < 0)
        {
            /* Concat With previous Layer Operation */

            currentView.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0f)));

            /* Need to set anchor point ==> Top Right Corner */
            currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.0f);

        }

        /* Flip The View Verticaly*/
        if(flipVerticle < 0)
        {
            /* Concat With previous Layer Operation */

            currentView.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0f)));

            if(flipHorrizontal < 0)
            {
                /* This needs to set as we have already done flip X */

                /* Need to set anchor point ==> Bottom Right Corner */
                currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                /* Need to set anchor point ==> Bottom Left Corner */
                currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
            }

        }

        /* Perform Rotation */
        if(angle != 0)
        {
            /* Concat With previous Layer Operation */

            currentView.layer.affineTransform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(CATransform3DConcat(currentView.layer.transform,CATransform3DMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(angle), 0, 0, 1.0)));

            if(flipHorrizontal < 0 || flipVerticle < 0)
            {
                /* Countinue with previous anchor point */
            }
            else
            {
                /* Need to set anchor point ==> Top Left Corner */
                currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
            }

        }

        /* Set Origins of View */
        currentView.layer.position = CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin);
        [self addSubview:currentView];
    }

}
```

Now I am looking to Move these added UIViews having transform.

Comment: did you fix your problem??

Comment: I have done with your direction but still facing same issues.

Comment: tell me your issues you have just to move the view up and down?

Comment: have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I am not able to maintain the transform" Anyway, here is a slightly different approach that I think may help you.

For starters, when you apply to a view a transform other than the 'Identity' transform the `frame` property becomes meaningless. This means you cannot use its `origin` member to change the view's position. You have to use the view's `center` property instead.

Also, for dragging, I strongly recommend you use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead of the `touches...` methods. This is because the gesture recognizer maintains state  for you and it's super easy to drag things around.

Here is some example code:

```
// Create your view and apply all the transforms you want
// --code here--

// Create and assign the UIPanGestureRecognizer
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[self.currentView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

// Here is where the dragging happens
-(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture {

    // Get the view that detected the gesture
    UIView *view = panGesture.view;

    // If dragging started or changed...
    if (panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        // Get the translation in superview coordinates
        CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:view.superview];

        // Get your view's center
        CGPoint viewCenter = view.center;

        // Add the delta 
        viewCenter.x += translation.x;
        viewCenter.y += translation.y;
        view.center = viewCenter;

        // Reset delta from the gesture recognizer
        [panGesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:view.superview];
    }
}
```

I tested this code in a project of mine with a view that has a rotation transform and it works perfectly.

Hope this helps!